# Kaldi_io error reading .scp/.ark files with python

Tags: python, deep-learning, speech-recognition, mfcc, kaldi

I need to read some scp file with the following code:

```py
for key,vec in kaldi_io.read_vec_flt_scp('raw_mfcc_dev_clean.1.scp'):
    print("mfcc of id ",key,"is equal to ",vec)
```

here's a line in the scp file: **1272-128104-0000 raw_mfcc_dev_clean.1.ark:17**

here's the error I get:

```py
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'raw_mfcc_dev_clean.1.ark:17\r\n'
```

P.S this directory **raw_mfcc_dev_clean.1.ark** exists

Comment: Looks the ark-filenames in you .scp file contain windows-style line endings (\r\n). Try converting your scp file to unix-lineendings.

Comment: @Johannes Yeah Johannes that what I did. solved it!